# Error in LibreOffice with "If Then" statement in Calc Macro

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am trying to convert a VBA macro from Excel into LibreOffice Calc.

I have included the necessary `Option VBASupport 1` line at the beginning.

My code throws an error when it gets to an IF ... THEN statement. These are the lines it is upset by:

```
If (WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1) < SplitRow Then 
resizeCount = WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1 
End If
```

and this is the error message:

```
BASIC runtime error.
'51'
Internal error .
```

here is the complete code. After some more testing it seems the Range object does not translate well into LO.

```
Option VBASupport 1
Sub SplitData()
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xRow As Range
Dim SplitRow As Integer
Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Select number of rows to split"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
SplitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Number", xTitleId, 5, Type:=1)
Set xWs = WorkRng.Parent
Set xRow = WorkRng.Rows(1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To WorkRng.Rows.Count Step SplitRow
    resizeCount = SplitRow
    If (WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1) < SplitRow Then 
    resizeCount = WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1 
    End If
    xRow.Resize(resizeCount).Copy
    Application.Worksheets.Add after:=Application.Worksheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Set xRow = xRow.Offset(SplitRow)
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: "It seems the Range object does not translate well into LO." And neither do most things! They are different platforms. Instead of trying to translate, you should remove `Option VBASupport 1` and rewrite the macro in LO Basic. An introductory resource is https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Comment: Perhaps you should not try to write this procedure again, this problem has been solved many times - just look for ready-made code. Maybe [**this code**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/split-data-or-range-into-multiple-worksheets/62849/6?u=johnsun) will work for you.

Comment: @JohnSUN that code probably would do what I wanted or could be easily adapted. However, the link in the post appears to be broken. Could you post a new link, please?

Comment: Oops! It was originally posted [**there**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=217990#p217990) (today I would write it a little differently)

Comment: A couple of issues with this macro. Whatever path you enter in the Source and Directory of Results fields it returns "The directory name "D:\xxx\yyy" not found and can not be created!" when you start the macro, despite having selected a folder using the browse buttons. I was able to get it to start if I but the ods file in the root folder, C:. Then the macro itself falls over with the error "BASIC runtime error. Object variable not set." at line 54. Sorry, I'm going to need a bit more help here. Thanks.